# predicting from flexmix object (R)

Tags: r, predict, mixture-model

I fit some data to a mixture distribution of two gaussian in `flexmix`:

```
data("NPreg", package = "flexmix")
mod <- flexmix(yn ~ x, data = NPreg, k = 2,
           model = list(FLXMRglm(yn ~ x, family= "gaussian"),
                        FLXMRglm(yn ~ x, family = "gaussian")))
```

the model fit is as follows:

```
> mod

Call:
flexmix(formula = yn ~ x, data = NPreg, k = 2, model =    list(FLXMRglm(yn ~ x, family = "gaussian"), 
    FLXMRglm(yn ~ x, family = "gaussian")))

Cluster sizes:
  1   2 
 74 126 

convergence after 31 iterations
```

But how do I actually predict from this model?

when I do

```
pred <- predict(mod, NPreg)
```

I get a list with the predictions from each of the two components

To get a single prediction, do I have to add in the cluster sizes like this?

```
single <- (74/200)* pred$Comp.1[,1] + (126/200)*pred$Comp.2[,2]
```

Answer (score 8):

I use `flexmix` for prediction in the following way:

```
pred = predict(mod, NPreg)
clust = clusters(mod,NPreg)
result = cbind(NPreg,data.frame(pred),data.frame(clust))
plot(result$yn,col = c("red","blue")[result$clust],pch = 16,ylab = "yn")
```

[image: Clusters in NPreg]

And the confusion matrix:

```
table(result$class,result$clust)
```

[image: Confusion Matrix for NPreg]

For getting the predicted values of `yn`, I select the component value of the cluster to which a data point belongs.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(result)){
  result$pred_model1[i] = result[,paste0("Comp.",result$clust[i],".1")][i]
  result$pred_model2[i] = result[,paste0("Comp.",result$clust[i],".2")][i]
}
```

The actual vs predicted results show the fit (adding only one of them here as both of your models are same, you would use `pred_model2` for the second model).

```
qplot(result$yn, result$pred_model1,xlab="Actual",ylab="Predicted") + geom_abline()
```

[image: Actual Vs Predicted]

```
RMSE = sqrt(mean((result$yn-result$pred_model1)^2))
```

gives a root mean square error of `5.54`.

This answer is based on many SO answers I read through while working with `flexmix`. It worked well for my problem.

You may also be interested in visualizing the two distributions. My model was the following, which shows some overlap as the ratio of components are not close to `1`.

```
Call:
flexmix(formula = yn ~ x, data = NPreg, k = 2, 
model = list(FLXMRglm(yn ~ x, family = "gaussian"), 
             FLXMRglm(yn ~ x, family = "gaussian")))

       prior size post>0 ratio
Comp.1 0.481  102    129 0.791
Comp.2 0.519   98    171 0.573

'log Lik.' -1312.127 (df=13)
AIC: 2650.255   BIC: 2693.133
```

I also generate a density distribution with histograms to visulaize both components. This was inspired by a SO [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114959/mixture-of-beta-distributions-full-example) from the maintainer of `betareg`.

```
a = subset(result, clust == 1)
b = subset(result, clust == 2)
hist(a$yn, col = hcl(0, 50, 80), main = "",xlab = "", freq = FALSE, ylim = c(0,0.06))
hist(b$yn, col = hcl(240, 50, 80), add = TRUE,main = "", xlab = "", freq = FALSE, ylim = c(0,0.06))
ys = seq(0, 50, by = 0.1)
lines(ys, dnorm(ys, mean = mean(a$yn), sd = sd(a$yn)), col = hcl(0, 80, 50), lwd = 2)
lines(ys, dnorm(ys, mean = mean(b$yn), sd = sd(b$yn)), col = hcl(240, 80, 50), lwd = 2)
```

[image: Density of Components]

```
# Joint Histogram
p <- prior(mod)
hist(result$yn, freq = FALSE,main = "", xlab = "",ylim = c(0,0.06))
lines(ys, p[1] * dnorm(ys, mean = mean(a$yn), sd = sd(a$yn)) +
        p[2] * dnorm(ys, mean = mean(b$yn), sd = sd(b$yn)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an additional argument to your prediction call.

```
pred <- predict(mod, NPreg, aggregate = TRUE)[[1]][,1]
```